# Compatibility between Yamaha FC3 sustain pedal and M-Audio 88 II keyboard

Tags: effects, hardware, keyboard, compatibility

Does a **Yamaha FC3** sustain pedal work with a **M-Audio Keystation 88 II** keyboard controller?

Answer (score 1):

No.

> The FC3 is only compatible with keyboards with half dampering
>   capability. We recommend the FC4 piano style pedal instead.
>
> NOTE: The FC3 is only compatible with: S90ES/XS, MOTIFXS/XF,
>   P120,140,155,P250, P60, P70, P85/P95,NP30, All CP series digital
>   pianos.

- [Yamaha FAQ](http://faq.yamaha.com/us/en/article/musical-instruments/keyboards/digitalpianos/p_series/p-95_color_variation/4713/3459)

From what I understand, the FC3 features "continuous sustain". This means that it is more than a simple on/off type of pedal: it can register how far down the pedal is pushed to give continuously variable sustain. However, the keyboard has to support this.

It appears the Keystation 88 II *does not*, unfortunately.

It is possible that the pedal will work with your keyboard but only as an on/off type, which means you will lose some functionality. (As an aside, all Keystation keyboards seem to feature an automatic polarity checker, making it possible to use a sustain pedal with any polarity.)

Answer (score 0):

Try it & see ;-)

There are only, as far as I know, 2 types of sustain pedal, press to open or press to close circuitry. Some machines can actually 'learn' which you plugged in if you do it before power-on.